# How to register one BroadcastReceiver object to tab bar application to show updates about network status in all activities present in the app?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-tabhost

I am working on tab bar application for Android and I need to update the user about status and I want to register the whole app to a `BroadcastReceiver` and show `Toast` in all screens about the network status.

I have come up with this below code but it is only for one `Activity`. I am registering in `onResume` the same way as I did in all activities but I am getting a null pointer for `currentNetworkInfo` in the second tab. Any ideas how to resolve this?

```
this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
            boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

            currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if (currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Network connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences for Storing Network Status from First Activity and read SharedPreferences from all other Activities

Comment: imran how to fire event when value changed in shared SharedPreferences in current activity when state changed?